# Disabling rainbow splash screen does not work

Tags: raspbian, boot, display, boot-issues, cmdline.txt

According to [elinux](http://elinux.org/RPiconfig), I should be able to disable the rainbow splash screen by setting this option in the `/boot/cmdline.txt` file:

> `disable_splash` if set to 1, avoids the rainbow splash screen on boot

My `cmdline.txt` looks like this:

```
dwc_otg.lpm_enable=0 console=ttyAMA0,115200 console=tty3 loglevel=1 root=/dev/mmcblk0p6 rootfstype=ext4 elevator=deadline rootwait quiet logo.nologo disable_splash=1
```

However, I still see the rainbow splash screen! I am using the latest Raspbian from NOOBS 1.3.9.

Why does that option not work?

Comment: Wait a minute. Which version os Raspian you using. The one installed using NOOB installer or zipping Raspbian image ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have edited the wrong file; `disable_splash=1` should be in `/boot/config.txt`.

Comment: No effect either :)

Answer (score 3):

Yes, but for the Raspberry Pi 3 model B, add the line:

```
disable_splash=1
```

to the file:

```
/boot/config.txt
```

is not hiding the splash screen with Raspbian Jessie

Comment: Can you explain what new information does your answer bring compared to the accepted one?

Comment: For me also, using `disable_splash=1` in `/boot/config.txt` doesn't prevent the color splash on boot.

Answer (score 2):

Seems like there is no way to get around the rainbow screen unless you switch to another bootloader. Checked from github and found the issue is been already addressed. This is a bug require fixing. Or you will to edit the binary (Which i would not recommened).

https://github.com/raspberrypi/noobs/issues/390

Answer (score 2):

For NOOB you need copy `config.txt` with command `disable_splash=1` to recovery partition.

```
cd /boot
sudo mkdir /media/recovery
sudo mount /dev/mmcblk0p1 /media/recovery/
sudo cp config.txt /media/recovery/
sudo reboot
```

Thats it, now no slpash screen show

Answer (score 1):

For me on Raspbian GNU/Linux 9 (Stretch) these modifications are working for making an absolute silent boot (boot to CLI):

In `/boot/cmdline.txt` change the console from `tty1` to `console=tty3`.

You'll also need to add `quiet splash loglevel=0 logo.nologo vt.global_cursor_default=0 fbcon=map:2`.

In `/boot/config.txt` uncomment or add `disable_splash=1`.

In `/etc/rc.local` add `dmesg --console-off` before `exit 0`.